# How to disable all the fields in a template driven form in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I created a template driven form in angular 5

I want to disable the whole form at first, and also want the form to be enabled once some button is clicked,  Hence I added a disabled property in the form tag and made its value as false as shown below , (this didn't work though):

```
<form #formName = "ngForm" [disabled]="true">
</form>
```

As the above disabled property didn't work, I changed the disabled property as

```
[attr.disabled] = true
```

This also didn't work

Now as I have the form element's reference which is `#formName`, I used it in the TS file and tried to change the disabled property value inside the reference object

Here's what I have done :

```
@ViewChild('formName') formName;


this.formName.disabled = true;
```

which also didn't work and I got an error message saying disabled cannot be changed as it is only a getter

How should I disable the whole form by default in angular on template driven forms ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: wrap the form using a `fieldset` tag and use `disabled` attribute as `<fieldset disabled>`

Comment: That's working but can I change the disabled value to false later on by binding a variable to disabled property in fieldset, Something like this 
<fieldset [disabled]="disabledValue">

Comment: I also want the form to be enabled later on when some button is clicked, Is it possible @Aravind

Comment: you can use that way and shall I answer that too post as it helped you?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you can wrap the form inside a `fieldset` tag and achieve this as below:

```html
<form>
    <fieldset [disabled]="fieldsetDisabled">
        <!-- YOUR FIELDS HERE -->
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And you can change handle the state in your controller by toggling a local variable and between the `disabled/enabled` states as:

```js
this.fieldsetDisabled = true;  // Disables the fieldset
this.fieldsetDisabled = false; // Enables the fieldset
```

Comment: This does not work in Angular 5.  The <fieldset> tag is not closed.  Even when I close it, it does not work.

Comment: Trying this in ng9, and it disables most controls except mat-select for some odd reason.

Comment: I have same problem as @sarora commented. Also it will not disable the validations. How to turn off validation for disabled fielset?

Comment: This works in Angular 13 with the normal reactive form. Any input, checkbox and button, etc. are disabled, I use it for a role based access + permissions (CRUD) system, for each field. Some forms need to be completely disabled on the page, while only specific fields are editable. For example, even though a user is ADMIN only designated admins can edit/update certain field(s)

Comment: The best solution is this, because [formGroup] should stay with the form tag:

<form [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="form">
  <fieldset [disabled]="!fieldsetDisabled">

<!--YOUR FORM FIELDS-->
  
</fieldset>
</form>

Comment: did not work for me (angular 13)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is this, because [formGroup] should stay with the form tag:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="form">   
 <fieldset [disabled]="!fieldsetDisabled">

<!--YOUR FORM FIELDS-->    
 
 </fieldset> 
</form>
```